# Updates controller-value and call controller-function from a directive. controller-calue not updated before function is called

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a controller-value that is bound to a value in my directive  with "=".

But when i update the value in the directive, and then call a function in the controller, the controller-value does not get updated before det controller function is executed.

This is how i implemented it:

**HTML:**

```
<my-directive page="searchCriterias.page" search-parent="search()" ></my-directive>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.searchCriterias: {page: 1};

        $scope.search = function() {
             SearchService.findCasesByCriteria($scope.searchCriterias).then(function (res) {
                //show search result
             }, function (e) {

             });
        }
    });


    app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div><button ng-click='nextPage()'>next</button></div>",
            replace: true,
            scope: { page: '=', searchParent: '&searchParent' }
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attr) {

                $scope.nextPage(){
                    $scope.page++;
                    $scope.searchParent();
                }

            }
        }
    )
```

The problem is that page is not updated before search function executed, so findCasesByCriteria is being excecuted with wrong page number. (If i ad timeout before calling $scope.searchParent() in the directive, the value gets updated before the controller-function gets called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is due to you are in a child scope. See here https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot for more infos.

Can you try with this :

```
<my-directive search-criterias="searchCriterias" search-parent="search()" ></my-directive>
```

and :

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div><button ng-click='nextPage()'>next</button></div>",
    replace: true,
    scope: { searchCriterias: '=', searchParent: '&searchParent' },
    link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
      $scope.nextPage(){
        $scope.searchCriterias.page++;
        $scope.searchParent();
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. `'='` creates a binding so that changing the attribute in the isolate scope is reflected in the attribute of the respective parent scope.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem! :) and @zeroflagL thats exactly what i also thought.
But i think maybe this solved the problem because it now is a object reference and not a reference to a value?

Comment: @Erex I guess it's because `searchCriterias.page` is not a property of the scope, but a property of a property. That would make sense.

Comment: When you pass an **Object**, you are passing **by reference** and not by value. That means that any change you do is applied to the same in-memory object. However, if you pass by value, Angular will still be able to apply the bi-directional binding, but only when the watchers are activated, which will only happen after the `nextPage()` has executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas that come to me straight away.

You could pass the controller function to the isolate scope using '&' instead of '='. By doing this you could call the function from the directive confident that the value has changed

Otherwise you could set a $watch on the variable in the controller that would call the function when the value changes

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to do anything. You just need to add $.apply() function before calling the function for directive.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div><button ng-click='nextPage()'>next</button></div>",
            replace: true,
            scope: { page: '=', searchParent: '&searchParent' }
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attr) {

                $scope.nextPage(){
                    $scope.page++;
                    $scope.$apply();
                    $scope.searchParent();
                }

            }
        }
    )
```

That's it It should work!!